# How can I customize the style of a foreign component without using the now-deprecated ::ng-deep?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, ngx-bootstrap, angular2viewencapsulation

In my app, I am using a component that comes from [`ngx-bootstrap`](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tabs).

I want to customize the look of the component (in this case, tabs), by making the tabs themselves appear green. Previously I could use `/deep/` in my SCSS, to target all selectors used within my component. But I do not want to use [something that is deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). So how can I get my code below, to turn the `a` tags within the `ngx-bootstrap` Tabs, yellow ?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'h3-my-component',
  template: `
    <h1>This is my COMPONENT</h1>
    <tabset>
    <tab heading="Tab 1" id="tab1">content</tab>
    <tab heading="Tab 2" id="tab2">content</tab>
  </tabset>`,
  styles: ['tab a { background-color: green }']

})
export class DemoTabsBasicComponent {}
```